# pytest fixture sqlalchemy transaction rollback doesn't work

Tags: python, transactions, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy, fixtures

I'm writing functional tests with pytest. My intention is to roll back transactions after each test in order to work with the same data in every test. Here's my code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def session(db, request):
   connection = db.engine.connect()
   transaction = connection.begin()

   options = dict(bind=connection, binds={}, autoflush=False, autocommit=True)

   db.session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

   def teardown():
       transaction.rollback()
       connection.close()
       db.session.rollback()
       db.session.remove()
   request.addfinalizer(teardown)

   yield db.session
```

But it doesn't work. Some tests fail because something before them was changed (and wasn't rolled back). And some tests fail with these errors:

```
FAILED ... - sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
FAILED ... - sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (r...
FAILED ... - sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (raised...
FAILED ... - sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (raised as a ...
FAILED ... - AssertionError: assert [{'id': 1, 'l...'Test'}, ...}] == [{'id': 1, 'l...'Test'}, ...}]
FAILED ... - AssertionError: assert 'updated-diagram' == 'test_1'
ERROR ... - sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No transaction is begun.
```

My comments:

- *...consider using a session.no_autoflush block...* - there is autoflush=False in session options
- *...To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback()...* - I also have that in teardown
- *AssertionError* - both of them are because of improper roll back
- *sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No transaction is begun.* - I have no idea what and why happened here

Comment: Would autocommit=True work in this scenario?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, it's already there

Comment: Ok, I've set autocommit to False and added session.commit where appropriate and it worked. After that were only assertion errors that occurred because of not making transaction rollbacks.